# Search html for text Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using urllib2 to get a web-page, and I need to look for a specific value within the returned data.

Is the best way to do this by using Beautiful Soup and using the find method or by using a regex to search the data?

Here is a very basic example of the text that is returned by the request:

```
<html>
<body>
<table> 
   <tbody> 
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="123" class="services">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> Example BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                        <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case I want to return "Example BLAB BLAB BLAB". The only thing that remains persistent within this is "Example" and I want to return all of the data within this particular  tag.

Answer (score 5):

[Don't use regular expression to parse html/xml.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2225682)

Using BeautifulSoup, you can use [css selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html_str = '''
... <html>
... <body>
... <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> Example BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
... <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
... <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
... <td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
... </body>
... </html>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)
>>> for td in soup.select('.style8'):
...     print(td.text)
...
 Example BLAB BLAB BLAB
 BLAB BLAB BLAB
 BLAB BLAB BLAB
 BLAB BLAB BLAB
```

Comment: It wouldn't work for my particular use case as I have not fully explained the structure of the data I think. I have edited the original post

Comment: @Ciaran, Do you want get the text of the first `td` element inside `div` with id `123`?

Comment: It prints nothing when I attempt to select by the css class. I can print the entire soup and can confirm that it is being rendered correctly

Comment: @Ciaran, There was a typo in the code. fixed it (`.styles8` to `.style8`). Check it out.

Comment: @falsetru, Yea I caught that originally, forgot to point it out :) Still doesn't work.. It won't print anything by their class name... My first script using python instead of PHP. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Ciaran, It works for me. See http://asciinema.org/a/7713 . By the way, did you install `bs4` (BeautifulSoup4), not `BeautifulSoup` (BeautifulSoup3) ?

Comment: @falsetru, I have installed bs4. I think it must be that beautifulsoup cannot parse a certain part of the page which is why it is unable to find the style8 class. Is there anyway to validate the content of the page or to skip non-parsable sections?

Comment: @Ciaran, The given html in the question works perfect as I show in the sccinema. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Ciaran, If the bs4 does not parse your content, please post a separated question about it.

Comment: @falsetru, Sorry for the misunderstanding, that is only part of the HTML content of the page. I will create another question. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated

Comment: @Ciaran, You'd better to include full content of the page, or the url in the question that answerer could retrieve.

Comment: Yea will do, the page is very lengthy which is why I did not post it here.